# Using clojure.spec to decompose a map

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I recognize that `clojure.spec` isn't intended for arbitrary data transformation, and as I understand it, it is intended for flexibly encoding domain knowledge via arbitrary predicates. It's an insanely powerful tool, and I love using it.

So much, perhaps, that I've run into a scenario where I am `merge`ing maps, `component-a` and `component-b`, each of which can take one of many forms, into a `composite`, and then later wanting to "unmix" the `composite` into its component parts.

This is modeled as two `multi-spec`s for the components and an `s/merge` of those components for the composite:

```
;; component-a
(defmulti component-a :protocol)
(defmethod component-a :p1 [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y ::z]))
(defmethod component-a :p2 [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::p ::q ::r]))
(s/def ::component-a
  (s/multi-spec component-a :protocol))

;; component-b
(defmulti component-b :protocol)
(defmethod component-b :p1 [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::i ::j ::k]))
(defmethod component-b :p2 [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::s ::t]))
(s/def ::component-b
  (s/multi-spec component-b :protocol))

;; composite
(s/def ::composite
  (s/merge ::component-a ::component-b)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is the following:

```
(def p1a {:protocol :p1 :x ... :y ... :z ...})
(def p1b (make-b p1a)) ; => {:protocol :p1 :i ... :j ... :k ...}

(def a (s/conform ::component-a p1a))
(def b (s/conform ::component-b p1b))
(def ab1 (s/conform ::composite (merge a b))

(?Fn ::component-a ab1) ; => {:protocol :p1 :x ... :y ... :z ...}
(?Fn ::component-b ab1) ; => {:protocol :p1 :i ... :j ... :k ...}

(def ab2 {:protocol :p2 :p ... :q ... :r ... :s ... :t ...})
(?Fn ::component-a ab2) ; => {:protocol :p2 :p ... :q ... :r ...}
(?Fn ::component-b ab2) ; => {:protocol :p2 :s ... :t ...}
```

In other words, I'd like to reuse the domain knowledge encoded for `component-a` and `component-b`, to decompose a `composite`.

My first thought was to isolate the keys themselves from the call to `s/keys`:

```
(defmulti component-a :protocol)
(defmethod component-a :p1 [_]
  (s/keys :req-un <form>)) ; <form> must look like [::x ::y ::z]
```

However, approaches where the keys of `s/keys` are computed from "something else" fail because `<form>` must be an `ISeq`. That is, `<form>` can neither be a `fn` that computes an `ISeq`, nor a `symbol` that represents an `ISeq`.

I also experimented with using `s/describe` to read the keys dynamically at run-time, but this doesn't work generally with `multi-specs` as it would with a simple `s/def`. I won't say I exhausted this approach, but it seemed like a rabbit hole of recursive `s/describe`s and accessing `multifn`s underlying `multi-spec`s directly, which felt dirty.

I also thought about adding a separate `multifn` based on `:protocol`:

```
(defmulti decompose-composite :protocol)
(defmethod decompose-composite :p1
  [composite]
  {:component-a (select-keys composite [x y z])
   :component-b (select-keys composite [i j k]))
```

But this obviously doesn't reuse domain knowledge, it just duplicates it and exposes another avenue of applying it. It's also specific to the one `composite`; we'd need a `decompose-other-composite` for a different composite.

So at this point this is just a fun puzzle. We could always nest the components in the composite, making them trivial to isolate again:

```
(s/def ::composite
  (s/keys :req-un [::component-a ::component-b]))
(def ab {:component-a a :component-b b})
(do-composite-stuff (apply merge (vals ab)))
```

But is there a better way to achieve `?Fn`? Could a custom `s/conformer` do something like this? Or are `merge`d maps more like physical mixtures, i.e. disproportionately harder to separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also experimented with using s/describe to read the keys dynamically at run-time, but this doesn't work generally with multi-specs as it would with a simple s/def

A workaround that comes to mind is defining the `s/keys` specs separate from/outside of the `defmethod`s, then getting the `s/keys` form back and pulling the keywords out.

```
;; component-a
(s/def ::component-a-p1-map
  (s/keys :req-un [::protocol ::x ::y ::z])) ;; NOTE explicit ::protocol key added
(defmulti component-a :protocol)
(defmethod component-a :p1 [_] ::component-a-p1-map)
(s/def ::component-a
  (s/multi-spec component-a :protocol))
;; component-b
(defmulti component-b :protocol)
(s/def ::component-b-p1-map
  (s/keys :req-un [::protocol ::i ::j ::k]))
(defmethod component-b :p1 [_] ::component-b-p1-map)
(s/def ::component-b
  (s/multi-spec component-b :protocol))
;; composite
(s/def ::composite (s/merge ::component-a ::component-b))

(def p1a {:protocol :p1 :x 1 :y 2 :z 3})
(def p1b {:protocol :p1 :i 4 :j 5 :k 6})
 (def a (s/conform ::component-a p1a))
(def b (s/conform ::component-b p1b))
(def ab1 (s/conform ::composite (merge a b)))
```

With standalone specs for the `s/keys` specs, you can get the individual keys back using `s/form`:

```
(defn get-spec-keys [keys-spec]
  (let [unqualify (comp keyword name)
        {:keys [req req-un opt opt-un]}
        (->> (s/form keys-spec)
             (rest)
             (apply hash-map))]
    (concat req (map unqualify req-un) opt (map unqualify opt-un))))

(get-spec-keys ::component-a-p1-map)
=> (:protocol :x :y :z)
```

And with that you can use `select-keys` on the composite map:

```
(defn ?Fn [spec m]
  (select-keys m (get-spec-keys spec)))

(?Fn ::component-a-p1-map ab1)
=> {:protocol :p1, :x 1, :y 2, :z 3}

(?Fn ::component-b-p1-map ab1)
=> {:protocol :p1, :i 4, :j 5, :k 6}
```

And using your `decompose-composite` idea:

```
(defmulti decompose-composite :protocol)
(defmethod decompose-composite :p1
  [composite]
  {:component-a (?Fn ::component-a-p1-map composite)
   :component-b (?Fn ::component-b-p1-map composite)})

(decompose-composite ab1)
=> {:component-a {:protocol :p1, :x 1, :y 2, :z 3},
    :component-b {:protocol :p1, :i 4, :j 5, :k 6}}
```

> However, approaches where the keys of s/keys are computed from "something else" fail because  must be an ISeq. That is,  can neither be a fn that computes an ISeq, nor a symbol that represents an ISeq.

Alternatively, you could `eval` a programmatically constructed `s/keys` form:

```
(def some-keys [::protocol ::x ::y ::z])
(s/form (eval `(s/keys :req-un ~some-keys)))
=> (clojure.spec.alpha/keys :req-un [:sandbox.core/protocol
                                     :sandbox.core/x
                                     :sandbox.core/y
                                     :sandbox.core/z])
```

And then use `some-keys` directly later.